# Bipartite graphs whose minimal cycles have length $4$

Tags: graph-theory

Is there some literature about bipartite graphs whose minimal cycles all have length $4$? By that I mean that any cycle in the graph with length strictly greater than four can be divided into cycles of length four ($Z^d$ is an example of such graph).

Thank you for the answer